# Consume only topic messages for a given account

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a service calculating reputation scores for accounts. It puts the calculation results in a Kafka topic called "ReputationScores". Each message looks something like this:

```
{ "account" : 12345, "repScore" : 98765}
```

I'd like my consumer to be able to consume **only** those messages for a specific account.

For example, I’d like to have a single instance of a consumer consume only messages with topic “ReputationScore” for account 12345. That instance should probably be the only member of its consumer group.

Can Kafka filter based on message contents? What's the best way to do this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You could create a partition specific to 12345 using custom partitioners and assign the cosumer to that partition instead of subscribing to the topic.

Comment: Do you mean you want to do a k/v lookup from your consumer of values in the topic for an arbitrary account? Or you want a given instance of a consumer to process a given account, but all messages to processed?

Comment: @A.Dev, thanks. I’ll check into that.

Comment: @Robin, I’ve updated the question with an example. Thanks for your help.

Comment: any idea about using `spring Kafka`? and i believe you are aware of Kafka offset acknowledgement  @JonathanM

Comment: @Deadpool, please explain. If you’d like, please put it in an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can Kafka filter based on message contents?

Since kafka itself doesn't know what's in your data, it cannot index it, therefore it's not readily searchable. You would need to process the full topic and have an explicit check for which deserialized records you want to parse. For example, this is what a stream processing application with a simple filter operation would provide you.

If you want to preserve the ability to do lookups by a particular item, you will either need to make a partitioner that segments all data you're interested in, or create a topic per item (which really only works for certain use cases, not things like individual user accounts).

You could look at inserting all events to an in-memory database, then performing queries against that